# NodeJs how to display table structured dashboard in console

Tags: linux, node.js

How can I create a dashboard looking display in the console through nodejs?

For example BFGMiner has a great looking structured UI:

[image]

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I would use https://github.com/yaronn/blessed-contrib it comes with a lot of widgets built-in.

Answer (score 3):

I personally use [cli-table](https://github.com/Automattic/cli-table), it works well

[image: cli-table]

Answer (score 3):

Rather than cli-table, you can use [tty-table](https://github.com/tecfu/tty-table) - which supports automatic word wrapping, colors, alignment, and cell padding.

[image]